# R group time column by condition eg. hourly

Tags: r, data.table

I have a time column like below.

```
Tcol <- as.data.table(c(1211, 1237, 2106, 1348, 2136, 1745, 1740, 1330, 1755, 1939, 2326, "NA"))
Tcol$V1= as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", Tcol$V1))
Tcol$V1[is.na(Tcol$V1)] <- 100
Tcol$V1 <- chron::chron(times=Tcol$V1)

Glimpse(Tcol)
Observations: 12
Variables: 1
$ V1 <S3: times> 1211, 1237, 2106, 1348, 2136, 1745, 1740, 1330, 1755, 1939, 2326,  100
```

I would like to group them by 1 hour blocks or 2 hours blocks for plotting.  ie.

```
100   1
1200  2
1300  2
1700  3
1900  1
2300  1
```

Searching other solutions on SO, it seems, I should be using cut().  But every time I apply cut(), I get an error.

```
table(cut(Tcol$V1, breaks="hour"))
Error in breaks + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I'm unable to find another post with the same issue to solve my issue.  So I'm hoping someone can help.

Comment: Perhaps `as.integer(droplevels(cut(as.POSIXct(chron(Tcol$V1)), breaks = "hour")))`

Comment: Error in as.POSIXct(chron(Tcol$V1)) : could not find function "chron"

Comment: The chron object you have there is not in units of hours. Try `chron(times=1211) # Time in days: 1211`. And if you did have it formatted as you want, I guess you should use `trunc.times` instead of `substr` in the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, then your `V1` column contains time in format `hm`.
I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish using `chron` function, but in your place, I would extract from `V1` only hour and then work with that.

```
# for 1 hour intervals:
Tcol[, h := as.integer(substr(V1, 1, 2))]
Tcol[, .N, by = h]

#for different intervals
breaks <- seq(0, 24, by = 2) # define breaks
Tcol[, newintervals := cut(h, breaks = breaks)]
Tcol[, .N, by = newintervals]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Tcol[,.(Count=length(.I)),by=.(Hour=100*floor(V1/100))]
```

Comment: This solution also worked.  But I assume to change the interval to 2 hours, I would need to change: Hours=200 and V1/200?